# .htaccess to nginx rules

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite, rules

I've read lots of threads here and in other community forums, also tried some htaccess to nginx generators, but I'm struck with this.

Thats my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
    RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here's my nginx configuration:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /$request_uri/ redirect;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
  }
}
```

When I run my script I'm being redirected in a loop

```
http://127.0.0.1////////////////////video/tkOVwe1x49C8wgi////////////////////
```

Will glad to get any help about this!

Comment: `try_files`.  Always use `try_files`.

Comment: Try: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php; }`

Answer (score 1):

While converting your first `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

you completely ignore the condition: don't rewrite anything already ending with `/` or containing a `.` (whatever purpose the second condition could have). You can rewrite it using a `location` block:

```
location ~ ^[^\.]*[^\./]$ {
    # No leading '/' like in the Apache rule
    return 301 $uri/;
    # rewrite (.*) $uri/ permanent;
    # has the same effect
}
```

As already remarked by **womble** and **Richard**, the second condition should be converted using `try_files`.

Altogether your rewrite rules should be:

```
location ~ ^[^\.]*[^\./]$ {
    return 301 $uri/;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
}
```

Comment: "whatever purpose the second condition could have" - I think the idea there is to avoid URLs that _look-like_ requests for files (ie. contain a file extension).